# DB2 SQL - WHERE TCODE is RI, RP or null...how to?

Tags: sql, null, db2

Having a really tough time coming up with a WHERE clause that only returns values for where my TCODE column is RI, RP or null.  Tried:

```
WHERE TCODE IN ('RI', 'RP', NULL)
```

and receive SQL0206 error.  Tried:

```
WHERE TCODE = 'RI' or TCODE = 'RP' or TCODE IS NULL
```

and receive SQL0199 error.

DB2 on IBM i, OS version 7.1

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!!

Matt

Edit for query:

```
SELECT T01.ORDRJI, T02.TCODE, T02.TRNDT, T02.TRQTY, T01.WHIDJI, T01.BUYRJI
FROM SCHRCP T01
LEFT OUTER JOIN IMHIST T02 ON T01.ORDRJI = T02.ORDNO 
AND T01.ITNOJI = T02.ITNBR AND T01.BKSQJI = T02.BLKSQ
LEFT OUTER JOIN ITMRVA T03 ON T01.ITNOJI = T03.ITNBR
LEFT OUTER JOIN VENNAM T04 ON T01.VNDRJI = T04.VNDNR
WHERE T01.DKDTJI BETWEEN 1170401 AND 1170630 AND
T02.TCODE IN ('RI', 'RP')and is null AND
T01.RSSTJI <> '99' AND
T01.WHIDJI <> '1' AND
T03.ITCLS IN ('BA', 'BF', 'BP', 'CA', 'CM', 'DF', 'EA', 'EP', 'FA', 
'FG', 'FM', 'FP', 'HJ', 'HT', 'JG', 'KT', 'LT', 'MA', 'MP', 'NF', 
'PA', 'PP', 'RB', 'RF', 'RP', 'RS', 'RU', 'SA', 'SF', 'RM', 'WA', 
'WP', 'DH', 'HD', 'MC') AND
T01.ITNOJI NOT IN ('CHARGES', 'MISC', 'MYLAR', 'CRATE', 'NRC', 'NRE')
```

Complete error:

```
SQL0199 - Keyword NULL not expected. Valid tokens: < > = <> <= !< !> != >= ¬< ¬> ¬= IN NOT
```

Comment: Can you please include your full query and the actual error message?  Your `WHERE` clause (the second one) looks fine.

Comment: Siyual - just edited to include that info.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
And T02.TCODE IN ('RI', 'RP')and is null
```

This is invalid syntax - you need to change this to

```
And 
(
    T02.TCODE In ( 'RI', 'RP' )
    Or T02.TCODE Is Null
)
```

But additionally, there are other problems with the query.  The `WHERE` clause is executed *after* the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, so these filters will cause your `OUTER JOIN` to behave as an `INNER JOIN`.

To fix this, add those `WHERE` conditions involving the outer table to the `ON` clauses:

```
Select T01.ORDRJI,
       T02.TCODE,
       T02.TRNDT,
       T02.TRQTY,
       T01.WHIDJI,
       T01.BUYRJI
From   SCHRCP T01
Left Outer Join IMHIST T02
    On T01.ORDRJI = T02.ORDNO
       And T01.ITNOJI = T02.ITNBR
       And T01.BKSQJI = T02.BLKSQ
       And (
               T02.TCODE In ( 'RI', 'RP' )
               Or T02.TCODE Is Null
           )
Left Outer Join ITMRVA T03
    On T01.ITNOJI = T03.ITNBR
       And T03.ITCLS In ( 'BA', 'BF', 'BP', 'CA', 'CM', 'DF', 'EA', 'EP', 'FA', 'FG', 'FM', 'FP', 'HJ', 'HT', 'JG', 'KT', 'LT', 'MA', 'MP', 'NF', 'PA', 'PP',
                          'RB', 'RF', 'RP', 'RS', 'RU', 'SA', 'SF', 'RM', 'WA', 'WP', 'DH', 'HD', 'MC'
                        )
Left Outer Join VENNAM T04
    On T01.VNDRJI = T04.VNDNR
Where  T01.DKDTJI Between 1170401 And 1170630
       And T01.RSSTJI <> '99'
       And T01.WHIDJI <> '1'
       And T01.ITNOJI Not In ( 'CHARGES', 'MISC', 'MYLAR', 'CRATE', 'NRC', 'NRE' );
```

Comment: Thanks, Siyual...I see what you mean.  (This was originally a query written in Query400 and I used rtvqmqry to use it in a visual editor).